# Read array in JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to read following JSON:

```
{
   "items":[
      {
         "snippet":{
            "title":"Pharrell Williams - Happy (12AM)",
            "categoryId":"10"
         },
         "topicDetails":{
            "topicIds":[
               "/m/04mn81",
               "/m/0zdjzxm"
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I've to read the `TopicIds` from the json. I've tried following to read the topicIds but it doesn't work. Please tell me what's wrong here:

```
  $.each(jsonResponse.items,function(key, value){
           $.each(value.topicDetails,function(k,v){
             for(var i=0, len = k.length; i< len; i++){
               alert(v[i]);
             }
           });
         });
}
```

It says there is no property `length'.

Comment: `topicDetails` is not an array and so has no `length` property. `$.each(value.topicDetails.topicIds)` instead

Comment: I'm getting this: `Cannot read property 'topicIds' of undefined`

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/LC7Ju/1/

Comment: Looks like you are trying to get the `length` of an object key, rather than the value.

Answer (score 1):

Read it like this:

```
$.each(data.items, function(key, value) {
    $.each(value.topicDetails.topicIds, function(k, v) {
        console.log(k, v);
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59GkP/)